# Book featuring humanity being updated and a boy leaving tapes because he can no longer be seen

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, young-adult

What I remember of the plot is that the boy was doing a show or something when an update happened to humanity, and now nobody can see or hear him. So he leaves tapes explaining what happened, and in the sequel the tapes are a book from the school the new protagonist is in.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this question by looking at the check lists in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), then [edit]ing it to include any further details that come to mind. In particular, it'd be helpful to know in roughly which year you read this, and when you think it might've been published.

Answer (score 14):

[Human.4](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8514163-human-4) by Mike A. Lancaster:

[image: Human.4]

> Kyle Straker volunteered to be hypnotized at the annual community talent show, expecting the same old lame amateur acts. But when he wakes up, his world will never be the same. Televisions and computers no longer work, but a strange language streams across their screens. Everyone’s behaving oddly. It’s as if Kyle doesn’t exist.
> Is this nightmare a result of the hypnosis? Will Kyle wake up with a snap of fingers to roars of laughter? Or is this something much more sinister?
> Narrated on a set of found cassette tapes at an unspecified point in the future, Human.4 is an absolutely chilling look at technology gone too far.

The sequel is [1.4](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11356936-1-4):

> It’s a brave new world. In the far future, people no longer know what to believe… Did Kyle Straker ever exist? Or were his prophecies of human upgrades nothing more than a hoax? Peter Vincent is nearly 16, and has never thought about the things that Strakerites believe. His father – David Vincent, creator of the artificial bees that saved the world’s crops – made sure of that. When the Strakerites pronounce that another upgrade is imminent, Peter starts to uncover a conspiracy amongst the leaders of the establishment, a conspiracy that puts him into direct conflict with his father. But it’s not a good idea to pick a fight with someone who controls all the artificial bees in the world.