# Sci-fi novel about a teen boy that's trying to figure out why people are disappearing

Tags: story-identification, novel

So I'm trying to find a book I read a couple years back. It's about this boy who thinks he's like experiencing ghost visits and all these unexplained phenomena. Meanwhile, there's like a new chip update coming for this computer chip everyone has in their head. But in the end, it turns out some people miss the update and so they get left behind in the last version and those in the new one can't see them. Also there was something about aliens.

Comment: I'm put in mind of _End of Days_ by Dennis Danvers but I don't think enough things match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's [Human.4](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8514163-human-4) by Mike Lancaster.

The [WorldCat summary](https://www.worldcat.org/title/human-4/oclc/827303844):

> Fifteen-year-old Kyle was hypnotized when humanity was upgraded to 1.0, and he, incompatible with the new technology, exposes its terrifying impact in a tape recording found by the superhumans of the future.

From a review on Goodreads:

> What if we could and have all been upgraded, countless times and what if some people just don't make the cut - forever lost and forgotten as obsolete hardware?

Comment: Also see [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/267663/139981). Though it doesn't have an accepted answer it's a dupe if this is the book OP is looking for.